# I want to know how principle of two-dimensional-array address is

Tags: arrays, c

I want to know how principle of two-dimensional-array address is.

When `M[4][5]` is declared. I thought `M=&M[0]`, `M[0]=&M[0][0]`. but `M`, and `&M[0]`, `&M[0][0]` is all same.
So I thought `*M!=M` but the results is same. I don't know principle of two-dimensional-array address.

my code is:

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
    
int main(){
    int M[4][5];
    printf("%d\n", *M);
    printf("%d\n", M[0]);
    printf("%d\n", &M[0]);
    printf("%d", &M[0][0]);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the tag for the language you are using, **not** the IDE you are using.

Comment: If you store a car in a garage, located in a house, then the house, the garage and the car can all be found at the same street address. Why exactly would they be on different street addresses?

Answer (score 1):

You're printing pointers, so you should be using

`printf("%p\n", (void*)...);`

Always turn on your compiler's warnings! I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with gcc/clang.

---

Here are the key bits of info you need:

- An array treated as a pointer degenerates into a pointer to its first element (`a == &(a[0])`).
- The address of an array is the same as the address of its first element (`&a == &(a[0])`).

The following is also useful to know, but wasn't used in my explanation:

- `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`.

---

Let's look at each statement (from bottom to top):

- `printf("%p", (void*)&M[0][0]);`

  You are printing the address of the first `int` of the first array of 5 `int`.
- `printf("%p\n", (void*)&M[0]);`

  `M[0]` is the first array of 5 `int`.

  This gets the address of that array, which is the address of its first element (the first `int`).

  This prints the address of the first `int` of the first array of 5 `int`.
- `printf("%p\n", (void*)M[0]);`

  `M[0]` is the first array of 5 `int`.

  `M[0]` is treated as a pointer. Therefore, it degenerates into a pointer to its first element (the first `int`).

  This prints the address of the first `int` of the first array of 5 `int`.
- `printf("%p\n", (void*)*M);`

  `M` is treated as a pointer. It degenerates into a pointer to its first element (a pointer to the first array of 5 `int`).

  `*M` is that array (the first array of 5 `int`).

  `*M` is treated as a pointer. Therefore, it degenerates into a pointer to its first element (the first `int`).

  This prints the address of the first `int` of the first array of 5 `int`.
- `printf("%p\n", (void*)M);` (BONUS!)

  `M` is treated as a pointer. It degenerates into a pointer to its first element (a pointer to the first array of 5 `int`).

  This prints the address of the first array of 5 `int`.

  The address of an array is the same as the address of its first element (the first `int`).

  This prints the address of the first `int` of the first array of 5 `int`.